# list comprehension in F#

Tags: list, f#, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I am trying to do some list comprehension in F#. And I found [this](http://en.csharp-online.net/FSharp_Functional_Programming%E2%80%94List_Comprehensions).

```
let evens n =
    { for x in 1 .. n when x % 2 = 0 -> x }
print_any (evens 10)

let squarePoints n =
    { for x in 1 .. n
      for y in 1 .. n  -> x,y }
print_any (squarePoints 3)
```

The first still works ok, but the second is outdated. The latest (1.9.7.8) F# compiler does not support this style.

After some search I found this works

```
let vec1 = [1;2;3]
let vec2 = [4;5;6]
let products = [for x in vec1 do for y in vec2 do yield x*y]
```

Can someone point why the syntax changed? Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

- Nested for loops require a `do`.
- You need to use `seq {..}`. The form `{..}` without `seq` doesn't work anymore.
- A `when` guard in a `for` loop pattern is also not supported anymore.
- `print_any something` is deprecated. Use `printf "%A" something` instead.

This code should work:

```
let evens n =
    seq { for x in 1 .. n do if x%2=0 then yield x }
printf "%A" (evens 10)

let squarePoints n =
    seq { for x in 1 .. n do
            for y in 1 .. n  -> x,y }
printf "%A" (squarePoints 3)
```

You can still use the `->` if all you want to do is return a single value:

```
let vec1 = [1;2;3]
let vec2 = [4;5;6]
let products = [for x in vec1 do for y in vec2 -> x*y]
```

By the way, I find it interesting to see how F# evolved over time. Too bad the early adopters have partially outdated books on their shelves (not that I mind).

Comment: Well, the early adopters didn't have much choice at the time :)

Comment: Neither did we early adopting authors. ;-)