# what is the difference between '->' and 'do' in a for loop, in F#

Tags: f#

I can do this:

```
[ for i in 0 .. 5 -> i ]
```

or

```
[ for i in 0 .. 5 do i ]
```

but, while I can do this:

```
[ for i in 0 .. 5 do yield! [i * 4; i] ]
```

I can't do that:

```
[ for i in 0 .. 5 -> yield! [i * 4; i] ]
```

why is that? how are the two treated differently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [list comprehension in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888451/list-comprehension-in-f)

Comment: So the takeaway from this link is that you can use -> when you just return a single value. But since they did a change in the compiler, was there a reason to keep -> instead of using ‘do’ for everything? Seems like -> is just one special case already covered by ’do’

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is quite tricky, because there are a few things here that F# does implicitly.

First, the `->` syntax is really just a shortcut for `do yield`, so the following translates as:

```
  [ for i in 0 .. 5 -> i ] 
= [ for i in 0 .. 5 do yield i ]
```

This explains why you cannot do `-> yield!` because the translation would result in:

```
  [ for i in 0 .. 5 -> yield! [i * 4; i] ]
= [ for i in 0 .. 5 do yield (yield! [i * 4; i]) ]
```

You would have `yield!` nested inside `yield`, which makes no sense.

The second tricky thing is the syntax with just `do`. This is a recent change in F# that makes writing list generators easier (which is fantastic for domain-specific languages that construct things like HTML trees) - the compiler implicitly inserts `yield` so the code translates as:

```
  [ for i in 0 .. 5 do i ]
= [ for i in 0 .. 5 do yield i ]
```

The interesting thing is that this works with multiple yields as well:

```
  [ for i in 0 .. 5 do 
      i
      i*10 ]

= [ for i in 0 .. 5 do 
      yield i 
      yield i*10 ]
```

This is another difference between `->` and `do`. With `->`, you can only yield one thing. With `do`, you can yield multiple things.

I imagine that there is very little reason for using `->` nowadays. This was in the language before the implicit `yield` and so it was useful in earlier versions of F#. You probably do not really need that anymore when `do` makes things as easy.